# Can I store state in __call__ of RNNCell

Tags: tensorflow

I want to build my own `RNNCell` (for a very simple cell where the output is [-1,0,1]), however in my `__call__` I do calculations that are dependent on the output of the previous time steps.

So my question is if it is possible to keep state in the `__call__` method to reuse between calls?

```
class MyCell(RNNCell):
    # Size of my state
    # My state consists of 1 tensor with num_units columns
    @property
    def state_size(self):
        return self._num_units

    # I emit at every timestep
    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return self._num_units

    def __call__(self,input,state):
        #Intermediate calculations for 1 time step
        #Can i keep state here, for example info about last input
        #or output?
        return output, new_state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work with `tf.dynamic_rnn`, so it is discouraged. Pass all state through the state argument if you want it to work. It might work with plain `tf.rnn` though it is not guaranteed.